# transfer integer over a socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, int

What is the appropriate way to transfer an `int` over a socket in C?
What I am doing so far is:

```
int n = 4;
int tmp = htonl(n);
write(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

and

```
int tmp,n;
read(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
n = ntohl(tmp);
```

However, the integer received is sometimes 0. Not always, but let's say 2 out of 5 times. It is never some other value, always 0. Why?

UPDATE: Return value from read is -1 and an error is:

```
Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: did you check the return value from `read` to see whether it actually filled the buffer?

Comment: The code snippit you provide is correct. Whatever problem you are having is in code you're not posting.

Comment: In case when 0 is received, return from read is -1. When actual integer is received, return from read is 4. This is I suppose ok, but still - how do I solve it? :/

Comment: Perhaps looking up what that `-1` means from `read`? It means you *didn't* read.

Comment: Provide complete reproducible code.

Comment: Did you set `O_NONBLOCK` on the socket? If so, then this error indicates that the data hasn't arrived yet. Try again later.

Comment: with `O_NONBLOCK` use select, poll, epoll or kqueue..

Comment: I think the correct way would be to poll the socket and read only when you are sure there's data on the socket available to be read...

Comment: Are you using a TCP socket that is blocking?

Comment: i am using a non-blocking TCP socket.

Comment: @Maggie: then either use blocking I/O, or otherwise wait until there is data available to read. You can't read data that has not yet arrived at your machine.

Comment: thanks everyone, I've managed to solve it at last

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, `sizeof(int)` may differ on your sender and receiver machine. So I would recommend you to use something like `int32_t` from `stdint.h`.

Also, it is not guaranteed that `read(..,..,sizeof(int))` will read exactly `sizeof(int)` bytes - it can read nothing, or it can read less bytes. So, the correct variant will be something more like this:

```
int send_int(int num, int fd)
{
    int32_t conv = htonl(num);
    char *data = (char*)&conv;
    int left = sizeof(conv);
    int rc;
    do {
        rc = write(fd, data, left);
        if (rc < 0) {
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                // use select() or epoll() to wait for the socket to be writable again
            }
            else if (errno != EINTR) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            data += rc;
            left -= rc;
        }
    }
    while (left > 0);
    return 0;
}

int receive_int(int *num, int fd)
{
    int32_t ret;
    char *data = (char*)&ret;
    int left = sizeof(ret);
    int rc;
    do {
        rc = read(fd, data, left);
        if (rc <= 0) { /* instead of ret */
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                // use select() or epoll() to wait for the socket to be readable again
            }
            else if (errno != EINTR) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            data += rc;
            left -= rc;
        }
    }
    while (left > 0);
    *num = ntohl(ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >UPDATE: Return value from read is -1.
Do you use nonblocking IO?

Comment: I think that the `receive` function is totally wrong. IMHO you used `ret` instead of `rc` that is actually never used

Comment: Also you should never look at errno unless read returned -1. You are inspecting it when 0 is returned which is going to lead to a bug that is really painful to track down

Comment: @garlix is right . Yes! In receive_int(), it should be 'if (rc <= 0) {' instead of  'if (ret <= 0) {'!!

Answer (score 17):

This should work without any problem, try this :

On the sender (Server) side :

```
int number_to_send = 10000; // Put your value
int converted_number = htonl(number_to_send);

// Write the number to the opened socket
write(client_socket, &converted_number, sizeof(converted_number));
```

On the receiver(client) side :

```
int received_int = 0;

return_status = read(client_socket, &received_int, sizeof(received_int));
if (return_status > 0) {
   fprintf(stdout, "Received int = %d\n", ntohl(received_int));
}
else {
   // Handling erros here
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks! +1 for `htonl` and `ntohl`

Comment: But this does not handle partial reads or writes!  read can return the result one byte at a time.

Comment: @D.Shawley You're right. This answer has the same problem as the question and solves nothing. You should downvote it for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and wasted 30 minutes trying to find out what I did wrong. But, finally, I found the solution. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-htonl) we can see that `htonl()` and `ntohl()` functions work with 32 bit unsigned integers. So, to fix the issue, you have to use `unsigned __int32` or `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

So the code will look like this:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t n = 4;
uint32_t tmp = htonl(n);
write(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

and:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t tmp,n;
read(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
n = ntohl(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one mentioned `sprintf`

you can just convert any **variable** to `char*` using it and send

```
if(strcmp(buf,"movUP") == 0)
{
    char* msg = calloc(1, 20);
    pos.y += 0.0001f;
    sprintf(msg,"NEW::POS::Y=%.4f", pos.y);
    sendto(master, msg, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, addrlen);
}
```

### Test

```
movUP
NEW::POS::Y=0.0001
movUP
NEW::POS::Y=0.0002
movUP
NEW::POS::Y=0.0003
movUP
NEW::POS::Y=0.0004
```

Use `%d` for integers, `%f` for floats

to **convert back** to an integer, use `atoi(char*)`
to **convert back** to an float, use `atof(char*)`

before converting, be sure to use `strstr()` to get the float value **only**, starting from `"0"`

```
    float myPos; // floating variable that stores Object's Position in the World
    ...
    ....
    memset(buf, 0, MAXBUFFER); // clears the previous buffer
    recvfrom(master, buf, MAXBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, &addrlen);
    char* newY = strstr(buf, "0");// NEW::POS::Y=0.0001 --->> 0.000100
    myPos = atof(newY); // new object's position by the server
    printf("My New Position is %.4f\n", myPos); // Out: My New Position is 0.0011 -> 0.0012 -> 0.0013 -> 0.0014.
```

For integers (**not** positions), you can use the same technique and just multiply it like

```
float f = 0.000002f; // that is supposed to be 2 integer value
int i = (int)(f*1000000); // now, i = 2
```

the above methods are totally secure

If you want a more solid converting, you can use `strncpy` or `memcpy` and cut the string starting from a given index with some length assuming that you already know the incoming buffer, but in my personal view, I don't really recommend it, specifically in **connectionless** sockets like this one, lots of calculations and calls for buffer length, Not easy to debug sometimes if you're not totally aware of what you're doing.

> **Note 1**: Be careful to **not** include **zeros** in your **buffer** when you're waiting for a server **move**/**position** command or any
>   quantity variable if you're planning to use the **1st** method.
>
> **Note 2**: You can just send your **integer** or **float**, **convert it** and **vice versa** without needing to **cut** or **multiply** it.

May new game networking developers find this answer useful too since we can't send or receive except `char*` with **UDP** sendto(), recvfrom().